# PHP script causes page to hang while loading

Tags: php, html, browser, ftp

I've done a lot of coding in the past regarding html and other languages, however only touched the surface of PHP.

I am trying to build an updating server status block on my game server site, and have got my code to a stage where in theory it should work, and my page produces no error messages, however I am experiencing the page to simply hang whenever I try to load it on my site, and if I try to view it locally it displays the PHP code raw as I do not have apache/PHP installed on my local machine.

I have done some testing, and my page loads absolutely fine if I remove or comment out the PHP code blocks, suggesting that my code is causing the error.

Here is the code I am trying to implement in the webpage. I am simply putting it in a `<span>` statement, and not using include from a file or anything like that.

```
<?php
        $conn = ftp_connect('SERVER');
        $file = 'status.txt';
        if (@ftp_login($conn, 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')) {
                ftp_pasv($conn, true);
                ftp_get($conn, $file, $file, FTP_ASCII);
                $status = file_get_contents($file);
                if ($status == 'online') {
                        echo '<span style="color:#00FF00;">Online</span>';
                } elseif ($status == 'offline') {
                        echo '<span style="color:red;">Offline</span>';
                } else {
                        echo '<span style="color:red;">Unknown</span>';
                }
        } else {
                echo 'Could not authenticate FTP server';
        }
        ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

This is my second shot at this code - I have also tried doing the same using `file_get_contents('ftp://ADDRESS');` instead of transfering the file from the FTP server, but I still got the page hanging, or displaying a PHP error if it gave one.

( If i leave the page long enough, I also get a 'Server sent no data' or 'Took too long to respond', and tend to get locked out of the website completely; as in getting this same error messages on pages I knew worked fine before, until I reset my IP address.

I have tried the webpage on both Chrome browser and Internet explorer, both browsers hang on the page. )

Comment: `until I reset my IP address` could you elaborate? If your IP changed, you reflect this in your connection, correct?

Comment: its hanging -as php is blocking, it will 'hang' until the timeout limit (60 seconds) is reached - the issue us fixing the ftp connection

Comment: @MattClark as in resetting my router to gain a new dynamic IP address assigned by my ISP. The entire site almost seems to almost blacklist my IP, and give me the same 'server sent no data' error for every page, even though they were fine before I tried loading the page tih my PHP scripting on.

Comment: shell access? try ftp there, it will tell you if its the script or the remote site

Comment: @Dagon The FTP connection is successful every time. As I am running the ftp server on one of my networked server machines, I can view the console, and it shows the user logging in successfully, transferring the file and disconnecting.

Comment: file_get_contents is not how you get a file via ftp .. you should be using ftp_get

Comment: @Dagon I am using ftp_get on line 6. I use that on line 7 to read the contents of the file to the $status variable as it should either contain 'online' or 'offline'

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks for that suggestion, I tried putting the lines in and re-uploading the file, however when I tried it, no avail with either chrome or IE. Even with error reporting, both browsers fail to load a page, chrome gets to 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE', and IE 'This page can't be displayed'.